# How to add timestamp to already existing objects using a value within the object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `MongoDb` database with around 1000 records, I had the `timestamp` option set to `false` and none of them has the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` attributes. Now i've set the `timestamp` to `true` and I want to update all the objects with `createdAt` `timestamp` to match a value within the object that is under `date` attribute, is that possible?

**For example:**

```
Review.findMany({}, $set: { createdAt: '<OBJECT>.date' }});
```

I want to update the `createdAt` with the value of the same object in `date` field.

Comment: you can use `updateMany()` method and [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { createdAt: { $exists: false } },
  [ { $set: { createdAt: { $toDate: "$_id"} } } ]
)
```

Comment: What `toDate` stands for?

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution**

So what I wanted to achieve in the first place was just to add `createdAt` attribute to all documents. The reason I want to do this manually is because I forgot to add the `timestamp` key to the Scheme, and already have around 1000 records in database.

**This is what I did:**

1. Created a new attribute in my object's Scehma called `createdDate`. (JavaScript)
2. Iterating all documents and updating the `createdDate` to the date (After conversion from `date`).
3. Connecting to Database using `Mongo Shell` (Assisted by [this link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/mongo/#:%7E:text=The%20mongo%20shell%20is%20an,well%20as%20perform%20administrative%20operations.)).
4. Navigating to the collection I want to edit.
5. Renaming `createdDate` to `createdAt` with this command:

   ```
   db.COLLECTION.updateMany({}, { $rename: { 'createdDate': 'createdAt' } })
   ```
6. Removing `createdDate` from Schema.

**Hope it helps someone!**